How can I pad a list column in a polars dataframe until the length of the list equals to the size indicated in another column?
I have two columns in a dataframe, pad_size and pad_start:
# Example Polars DataFrame with arrays pad_start and pad_size
data = {
    'pad_size': [5, 4, 3],
    'pad_start': [[1, 2], [4, 5, 6], [7]]
}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)

I would like to output another column, pad_end, where pad_end = pad_start + append 0s until length of pad_end = pad_size
Desired output:
data = {
    'pad_size': [5, 4, 3],
    'pad_start': [[1, 2, 0, 0, 0], [4, 5, 6, 0], [7, 0, 0]]
}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)


I'm using polars 0.18.4 due to some limitations
I tried to use various list functions, and the closest I got was to concat a bunch of 0s, and then slice it, but that doesn't seem to scale very well (works only for a certain range of pad_size)
Current best solution
df_int = df.with_columns(zero = pl.lit(0)).with_columns(pl.col('zero').repeat_by(pl.col('pad_size') - pl.col('pad_start').list.lengths()))

df_int.with_columns(
   pl.col('pad_start').list.concat(pl.col('zero')).alias('pad_end')
   )

will create a pad_end column along with a zero column, which adds the number of [0] required

You can use:

.repeat_by() to generate the pad list
.list.concat() to append

# so we can see the result properly
pl.Config(fmt_table_cell_list_len=-1)

df.with_columns(
   pl.col('pad_start').list.concat(
      pl.lit(0).repeat_by(
         pl.col('pad_size') - pl.col('pad_start').list.len()
      )
   )
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌──────────┬─────────────────┐
│ pad_size ┆ pad_start       │
│ ---      ┆ ---             │
│ i64      ┆ list[i64]       │
╞══════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 5        ┆ [1, 2, 0, 0, 0] │
│ 4        ┆ [4, 5, 6, 0]    │
│ 3        ┆ [7, 0, 0]       │
└──────────┴─────────────────┘

(note: to run on 0.18.4 the only change required should be changing .list.len() to .list.lengths())

I get this error: ComputeError: Length of repeat_by argument needs to be 1 or equal to the length of the Series. Series length 1, by length 3. I'm guessing it has got to do with the type?

@benedictine_cumbersome It seems before 0.19.0 you needed to manually "broadcast" the height of the literal value first by adding it as a column, i.e. .with_columns(zero = pl.lit(0)).with_columns(pl.col('zero').repeat_by(...))

I'm not sure if I understood your solution correctly, but when I created an intermediate df which has the required [0], then concat it I got the result I wanted (updated in body)

@benedictine_cumbersome Yes, it was a "bug". https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/10735


repeat_by() to create a list of 0 of size pad_size.
list.concat() to concat 2 lists.
list.head() to get first pad_size elements.

df.with_columns(
   pl.col.pad_start.list.concat(
      pl.lit(0).repeat_by(pl.col.pad_size)
   ).list.head(pl.col.pad_size)
)

┌──────────┬─────────────────┐
│ pad_size ┆ pad_start       │
│ ---      ┆ ---             │
│ i64      ┆ list[i64]       │
╞══════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 5        ┆ [1, 2, 0, 0, 0] │
│ 4        ┆ [4, 5, 6, 0]    │
│ 3        ┆ [7, 0, 0]       │
└──────────┴─────────────────┘

or

concat_list() to concat columns.

df.with_columns(
    pl.concat_list(
        pl.col.pad_start, pl.lit(0).repeat_by(pl.col.pad_size)
    ).list.head(pl.col.pad_size)
)

┌──────────┬─────────────────┐
│ pad_size ┆ pad_start       │
│ ---      ┆ ---             │
│ i64      ┆ list[i64]       │
╞══════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 5        ┆ [1, 2, 0, 0, 0] │
│ 4        ┆ [4, 5, 6, 0]    │
│ 3        ┆ [7, 0, 0]       │
└──────────┴─────────────────┘

